# Handle post request in backbone

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

New to backbone, I am building a backbone application which uses rails APIs. This application involves PayU integration. 
I am able to send POST parameters to PayU (via submitting a hidden form) to initiate/redirect to the gateway.

But i am stuck capturing the response from PayU in my Backbone application, as PayU send response parameters via POST request that i need to capture in my backbone application and then further send to rails API.

How backbone route handled POST requests? Is there anyway i could do that? If not, then kindly let me know a different approach to implement this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Backbone route has nothing to do with your AJAX calls. To initiate ajax call (get,put,pust etc) you need to use [Backbone.Model](http://backbonejs.org/#Model) objects and use their fetch or save or update methods

Comment: The above code snippet is used to send POST request to PayU from backbone application and is working fine, once i redirected to PayU interface and after making payment PayU redirects back to my backbone application with a POST request which is supposed to be handled by Backbone application, but as far as i had searched i found noway to handle a POST request in backbone router.

Comment: removed code snippet, as it might creating confusion to actual problem.

Comment: are your html and JS still available at client side after you redirect to payU gateway?

Comment: No, PayU takes a cancel and success URL on which it redirect via POST after transaction.

Comment: then in that case you need to provide a URL which will accept the data. i.e you need to provide a URL of REST/SOAP service which will in turn load your HTML and JS at client

Comment: This is what i had done, but this looks like a weird solution. Is it correct to have API action that redirect to client instead of rendering JSON/XML? This API action might get messed up if i have multiple clients. So it seems like Backbone is purely client side framework that supports only GET request.

Comment: Since you need to catch data from post. It seems to have the only solution. Since no client will be accept the post data.

Comment: Alright nikhil, thanks for help.